# SDL Sprite how to set sprite center of origin

Tags: 2d, sdl, sprite

I'm messing around in SDL trying to build a game and have noticed that when I blit a sprite to the screen the origin of the sprite is set to the top left corner, 0,0.

To get around this I've simply adjusted the sprite placement by 1/2 the sprites width but as a solution it feels kind of clunky - I want to build a platform game so surely the COO will need to be at the sprites feet for collision detection with the platforms - and I was wondering if SDL had any functions in place that would allow me to set the center of origin a bit like the sprite editor in construct2.

This is my drawing routine:

```
// Draws the hero sprite according to clipframe
void apply_surface( int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination,      SDL_Rect* clip = NULL )
{
  //Holds offsets
  SDL_Rect offset;
  //Get offsets
  offset.x = x;
  offset.y = y;
  //Blit
  SDL_BlitSurface( source, clip, destination, &offset );
}
```

My instantiation of it:

```
 apply_surface(width /2 - heroSpriteSize /2, height /2 - heroSpriteSize /2, hero, buffer, &wait[frame]);
```

Comment: Can't you just change `apply_surface`? Or create a wrapper for it?

Comment: apply surface is handling a couple of sprites so if I alter the offset in that their positions are changed as well. The way I'm using apply_surface is positioning the sprite correctly, but I don't expect collisions with screen boundaries to handle very well.

Comment: The why not use a wrapper than in turn calls `apply_surface`? Or you could add a `bool` that states whether the sprite should be drawn from upper left or the center.

Comment: Btw; it's not hard to make your collision detection handle sprites that are drawn from upper left. 

Also your call to `apply_surface` looks wrong to me. It should be something like `apply_surface( sprite.x + ( sprite.w / 2 ), sprite.y + ( sprite.h / 2 ) )`

Comment: I see what your getting at, so I would create another surface and then blit the sprite to it to adjust the object centre. I thought the apply_surface call looked wrong as well, I'll check out your amends.

Comment: Btw; you should have a `SDL_Rect` to for each object that you use both for drawing and collision detection. You can easily rewrite the `apply_surface()` to handle `SDL_Rect` instead of `int x, int y`